# Change row format on production servers?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am currently prepping to upgrade from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.

I am using RDS on AWS with a master server and read replicas. The read replicas use MySQL replication but are read-only copies.

One of the issues I need to resolve prior to upgrade is that I have some tables on production databases with COMPACT row format which need updating to DYNAMIC.

I know I can do this with the following and have a script which will find and update all tables needed.

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

There are a large number of potentially large tables (millions of rows) that need updating.

What does this change actually do in the background? Is it safe to run this on a production server whilst it is in use? Does it lock the tables whilst it makes the change?

I have run a test on a restored copy of the server. This takes a while as I'd expect, and as such it's hard for me to test to be sure everything is working fine during this whole process. It does complete successfully eventually though

Comment: Create yourself a test environment, load a database from a backup. Try ALL the changes in the test environment, Keep a stop clock by your desk. You will learn a lot in the process,

Comment: Sorry, I have already done that - I'd put that in the question but accidentally removed when it merged the "What have you tried" text with the question. I've updated the question.

Comment: Well if you find it hard to know if "everything is working fine" you will have to do some testing, serious testing! Or how will you know that this is safe to do on your LIVE database? You will have to invent some tests

Comment: If anyone can advise what MySQL is actually doing, that would help me target my testing at the right times/processes. Does it do a table rebuild? Does it lock the table at any point? At what point does it lock the table? Is it just doing everything in a temporary table/space and doesn't touch anything live until it complete Etc. Thanks for your input, @RiggsFolly, but obviously I need to and am testing.

Comment: That Alter will create a new table with the revised FORMAT, then copy all the rows over and rebuild the indexes.  Then it will swap tables and drop the old.  `SHOW TABLE STATUS;` should show that things look good.

Comment: And, yes, the table will be locked.  I would avoid doing any writes to any table during the Alters -- JOINs could timeout or do other nasties.

Comment: @RickJames - thank you - that is very helpful and is what I was looking to find out. I think I have come up with a way I can do this on one of my replicated instances and then switch people over which will certainly make things a lot simpler/less risky!